# Is it possible to implement Passkeys with php?

Tags: php, passkey

I'm new to Passkeys and I was wondering if it is possible to use php to implement them as seen here: https://www.passkeys.com

Thanks and hopefully this isn't a silly question.

I've looked at OwnID and they have NodeJS, Python, and other integrations, but I would like to use php if possible.

Comment: That site is made by a particular vendor to get you to buy their services. Passkeys work based off an open standard named Webauthn; https://github.com/web-auth/webauthn-lib is a PHP lib for working with it.

Answer (score 1):

If it can be done in one programming language it's generally possible in others ;) https://github.com/herrjemand/awesome-webauthn lists multiple PHP implementations.